# Delete query deletes entries from two tables with expo-sqlite

Tags: react-native, sqlite, expo-sqlite

I have two really simple tables, without any constraint between them:

```
CREATE TABLE groups (groupId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, groupName TEXT)

CREATE TABLE savedRuns (runId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, runName TEXT, groupId INT NULL, startTime TEXT, stopTime TEXT, elapsedMilliseconds INT)
```

Whenever I delete an entry from the `group` table, the entry in `savedRuns` which has the same `groupId` is also deleted. **I do not want that!**

This is the delete query:

```
DELETE FROM groups WHERE groupId = 1
```

I can't understand this behavior as there are no foreign key constrains between the two tables!

I'm using SQlite from the `expo-sqlite` library in my React Native app.

My final goal is to enabled foreign keys and set the `groupId` to `null` in the `savedRuns` table, but I think I should figure out the first problem first.

I even ran `PRAGMA foreign_keys` and got 0 as result

Comment: If you are sure that *there are no foreign key constrains between the two tables* then check for triggers.

Comment: `select * from sqlite_master where type = 'trigger'` returns an empty array. I guess there wouldn't be any trigger until I create them anyways?

Comment: The behavior that you describe is not consistent with the table definitions in your question. Cascaded deletes happen only when they are enforced by foreign key constraints or triggers.

Comment: yes, that is my understanding as well. I will investigate further... maybe something wrong with my Delete function...

Answer (score 0):

All the queries above were fine. The problem was with my `SELECT` query which didn't display the entries without a `groupId` in the `groups` table.

Changing the `INNER JOIN` to `LEFT JOIN` in my SELECT query fixed the issue!